# How to get to different and multiple view from controller route Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, view, rails-routing

I'm moving a Sinatra app I made a while back to Rails 4. In my Sinatra app I had a helper called "logged_in" that returned true if the a user was logged in and returned false otherwise. Then in my routes I had the following...

```
get '/' do
  if logged_in
    erb :"admin/a_index"
  else
    erb :index
  end
end

get '/about' do
  if logged_in
    erb :"admin/a_about"
  else
    erb :about
  end
end

get '/contact' do
  if logged_in
    erb :"admin/a_contact"
  else
    erb :contact
  end
end
```

So that if the user was logged in, it would render a different admin view (located in a sub-folder) for that specific static page. If the user wasn't logged in, it would render a default static page.

How can I implement this in Rails 4?

Do I have to specify extra admin routes or can I do something like the following... ?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if logged_in
      render #admin_home
    else
      render #home
    end
  end

  def about
    if logged_in
      render #admin_about
    else
      render #about
    end
  end

  def contact
    if logged_in
      render #admin_contact
    else
      render #contact
    end
  end
end
```

with just the following routes...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'
  get '/home' => 'pages#home'
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  get '/contact' => 'pages#contact'

  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally just do:

```
if logged_in?
  render  'admin/index'
else
  render 'index'
end
```

But the convention that I've seen in Rails is to have an admin namespace for controllers and views. If you're using Devise, it [looks like](http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/) you can write signed in routes like so:

```
authenticated do
  get '/home' => 'admin/pages#home'
end
```

Which means, of course, that you'd have to specify the same routes for non-signed in users. But then you'd have a separate controller (AdminPagesController in contorllers/admin) and action for admin in case you need to load different data. Views would then go in views/admin/.

Comment: Aw perfect! Your first suggestion worked nicely. I also appreciate you mentioning the more popular convention; I'm looking into name-spacing now.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. Render only renders a specific page, it doesn't call any new routes. That is what `redirect_to` does: it calls a whole new route. You can call `render` for any view in your application, just as long as you have the right instance variables to make it display properly.